# JIRA comment tag name

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

While commenting on JIRA tickets, `@username` can be used to tag a team member. The thing that bugs me is that when I try to tag any team member, there is a special encoded text appear (something like this `[~gbuc13]`) for every person you tag in. 
Now its very difficult to find which member you tagged in your comment by seeing this code. Is there any way that this strange encoded name could be replaced with a proper, meaningful names so that when a user is being tagged, `[mike]` is appeared instead of `[~gbuc13]`? I know this change will have to be adopted by every team member to define their aliases, but I am wondering where this (alias?) could be set.

Comment: The "alias" you're referring to is strictly the JIRA username, and as far as I know, you can't change it without changing the username. But this is only an issue when writing the comment, right, since JIRA should render the full user display name when the comment is saved. If you just want to see the names while writing the comment, try clicking the blue "Preview" icon in the bottom left corner of the comment area.

Comment: JIRA has three properties for user: user key, user name and full name. Full name is used when you tag a user. Only thing you can't change is user key, you can change user name and full name. The alias - username - can be changed when editing single user (Edit profile).

Answer (score 1):

The change you describe is is the difference between the saved view and the edited view and can't be changed:

- at edit time you see the alias
- once saved you see the full user name (which links to the Jira profile page showing all their activity)